# My django app url reversing is not working

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I have a web application which I have split into several applications. I think this might have been an over exageration on my part but regardless I want to make this work and understand what my problem is.

To those apps I have a list of buttons with the links:

```
<li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="link-text">Home</span></a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'resume:index' %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="link-text">Resume</span></a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'services:index' %}"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i><span class="link-text">Services</span></a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'portfolio:index' %}"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i><span class="link-text">Portfolio</span></a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog:index' %}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i><span class="link-text">Blog</span></a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contact:index' %}"><i class="fa fa-address-book"></i><span class="link-text">Contact</span></a></li>
```

The urls for these are stored in the webapp/urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('dashboard.urls')),
path('resume/', include('resume.urls')),
path('portfolio/', include('portfolio.urls')),
path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
path('services/', include('services.urls')),
path('contact/', include('contact.urls'))
]
```

And in each webapp/app/urls.py file I have the urlpatterns as such:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Currently I am having two issues with this.
( 1) The dashboard link does not work and I get the error "No reverse match for 'dashboard' " ) <- No longer an issue
2) My second issue is that the other urls do not redirect to anything when I click on the button. The webapps show up however if I navigate through the address bar to them.

Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Comment: Can you show dashboard/urls.py file?

Comment: Yea the one that I showed is the dashboard/urls.py. I just realized that I was missing the app name for it and that's why it couldn't find it.

Comment: have you specified `app_name` in each `urls.py` file?

Comment: @RustamGarayev Now yes